# When I create a local xml file I get an error importing carrot2

Tags: carrot2

I am trying to create a local xml file for import. The tags specified in https://doc.carrot2.org/#figure.input-xml-format give me an error. Specifically, I get the error:

> "Failed to read attributes from:
>   /lungo/home/holz/nestlib/extras/text/carrot2/goodpubmed.xml Element
>   'query' does not have a match in class
>   org.carrot2.util.attribute.AttributeValueSets at line 2".

If I remove query, I get the error with 'document' Element. I have just downloaded the latest version for `linux` with `java` 1.8.

Comment: You're probably trying to load your XML file to the attribute view rather than process it through the clustering algorithm. Here's how you can pass your XML file as data for clustering: https://doc.carrot2.org/#section.getting-started.xml-files. If this doesn't work, please paste a sample of your XML for inspectin.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem. I was loading in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to load your XML file to the attribute view rather than process it through the clustering algorithm. Here's how you can pass your XML file as data for clustering: http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.getting-started.xml-files.